# DFS problem solving with recursion how does it work?

Tags: python, recursion, depth-first-search

Here's the problem

There are n nonnegative integers. We want to add or subtract these numbers appropriately to make our target number. For example, to make the number 3 out of [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], you can use the following five methods:

```
-1+1+1+1+1 = 3
+1-1+1+1+1 = 3
+1+1-1+1+1 = 3
+1+1+1-1+1 = 3
+1+1+1+1-1 = 3
```

Write the solution function to return the number of ways to make the target number by adding and subtracting the numbers appropriately when the array numbers, target number and target are given as parameters.

Restrictions

- The number of numbers given is 2 or more and 20 or less.
- Each number is a natural number from 1 to 50.
- The target number is a natural number from 1 to 1000.

I/O example

```
numbers: [1,1,1,1,1]
target: 3
return: 5
```

approach

```
                                    1

                                  /   \

                               -1       1

                             /   \     /   \

                           -1     1  -1     1
                           
                           -1     1   1     3
```

found this approach in DFS manner, checking all the cases, either addtion or substraction if the combination of the numbers equals to target number then count.

Code below:

```
def solution(numbers, target):
    total = 0
    num_len = len(numbers)

    def dfs(index=0):
        if index < num_len:
            numbers[index] *= 1
            print('positive / index', index, numbers)
            dfs(index + 1)

            numbers[index] *= -1
            print('negative / index', index, numbers)
            dfs(index + 1)

        else:
            if sum(numbers) == target:
                nonlocal total
                total += 1
                print('matched / index', index, numbers)

    dfs()

    return total
```

However, I was wondering how it runs so did console logging.

```
positive / index 0 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
positive / index 1 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
positive / index 2 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
positive / index 3 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] 
positive / index 4 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
negative / index 4 [1, 1, 1, 1, -1]
matched / index 5 [1, 1, 1, 1, -1]
negative / index 3 [1, 1, 1, -1, -1] ### how come this index all of sudden becomes 3? ###
positive / index 4 [1, 1, 1, -1, -1]
                ...
```

I kind of understand increment of the index recursively til matched / index 5
but not too sure why right next time it becomes 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logging format may be confusing you. After 5, there are no more recursive calls to be made so the next printed line is associated with an older stack frame that's been sitting waiting for its children to resolve before exploring the next recursive call chain.

If you add indentation you'll see the parent-children relationships more clearly:

```
print("  " * index + 'positive', numbers)
```

```
0 1 2 3 4 5     stack depth
===========================
positive [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
  positive [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    positive [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
      positive [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
        positive [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
        negative [1, 1, 1, 1, -1]
          matched [1, 1, 1, 1, -1]
      negative [1, 1, 1, -1, -1]  <-- here's the call you asked about
      ... calls continue ...
```

Here, you can see that the negative branch your question is about is back in depth 3 and isn't a child of `matched`. After the `matched` call, there are no more child nodes to explore and the stack pops back to the parent, which also has no further nodes to explore and pops back to its parent at depth 2, which still has its `negative` child call chain to explore, which it does, spawning its second call to depth 3.

Comment: so like the way of recursive function works, calling itself til it can and runs like backward, depth3 reached the end (got no more to go) meanwhile others waiting so looking up depth2 which still got some to go that I asked about and it was index3 back then it called?

Comment: Yep, exactly. When a function is called, it can't finish execution until every child recursively resolves. The top level function is "on hold" until all of its children figure out how many matches can be made all the way down to the terminal nodes that stop spawning calls. as in your image, a call tree is created that branches out, trying every legal possibility.

Comment: You could also add a print at the end of each function that says "finished with this stack frame" or something and you'd see those pops printed on the way back to depth 3 from the depth 5 match.